# "Трудоустройство на работу" - это не тавтология?

Tags: стилистика

Comment: Она самая. Либо "трудоустройство", либо "устройство на работу"

Answer (score 1):

Больше похоже на плеоназм: "труд" и "работа" имеют разные корни.

Answer (score 0):

Да, *"трудоустройство на работу"* - это плеоназм, а не тавтология. Так говорить нельзя. 
*"Устройство на работу"* звучит как-то нелепо, по-моему, ибо *"устройство"* в современном языке уже чаще обозначает предмет (пример: *зарядное устройство*), а не действие.

Comment: "Устроиться на работу" вполне возможно. Отсюда и "устройство на работу" не выглядит невозможным. Правда канцелярщиной сильно отдаёт.